# Find timestamp in tcpdump packet capture

Tags: unix, tcl, wireshark

I need to verify the packets flowing between the two phones , for that i have collected the tcpdump by the use of this command:-     `tcpdump -s 65535 -w filename.pcap`

then i have converted this file in to text file by command:-    `tshark -V -r packetTB.pcap  > asd.txt`

but in this text file i don't see any time stamp available, is there any command in unix by which i can get the time stamp also, is there any way in tshark command by which we can get the time stamp

Comment: Don't you get to see `Arrival Time` in your converted text file?

Answer (score 1):

As per Prabhu's answer, unless there's something horribly wrong with the version of tshark you're using, there should be a line saying something like

```
Arrival Time: May 19, 1999 17:48:39.708517000 PDT
```

in the output of tshark; that's the time stamp.

You can also get the time stamp with tcpdump.

If there are only some fields of the packet you want, try the `-T fields` option of tshark, using the `-e` flag to specify the names of the fields you want.  For example, `frame.time` is the timestamp field.

Comment: can you please elaborate it how to get the exact time stamp code....how to write it?